# Calculate window height after page is fully loaded jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, screen-orientation

I have dymanically changed interface with orientation change. I calculate my `<div>` size throu `$(window).height()`, but it calculating not after page is fully loaded, but before it. How can I do it in Jquery mobile?

Comment: height of viewport or height of page with contents inside it?

Comment: `$.mobile.getScreenHeight()` you can call it at anytime.

Comment: But what about Width? I need it too

Comment: `$(window).width()` should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `resize()`

For example :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  console.log($(window).height());
});
```